# How to manually know the RSA2 key finger print?

Tags: ssh, rsa

When I grep in the etc folder, I get this message:

```
grep: ssh_host_rsa_key: Permission denied.
```

Since I am on cygwin, I can't use sudo or something else.

Please let me know how to find it out.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
ssh-keygen -l -f /etc/ssh_host_rsa_key.pub
```

This command will output just the fingerprint like this:

```
2048 9e:1a:5e:27:16:4d:2a:13:90:2c:64:41:bd:25:fd:35 /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key.pub
```

-f is for filename
-l is to output the fingerprint of the public key file.

Output consists of three parts

- **bit length of the key:** `2048`
- **finger print of the key:** `9e:1a:5e:27:16:4d:2a:13:90:2c:64:41:bd:25:fd:35`
- **name of the key file:** `/etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key.pub`

I would like to request experts on this matter to point any shortcomings in this method.

Comment: You left out a file folder in the command line. The file is under /etc/ssh/'filename'
You put /etc/'filename' Cheers!

Comment: For new version of openssh, use 
    ssh-keygen -E md5 -lf /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key.pub
to get the fingerprint with md5 hash format. The default is the sha256 format.

Answer (score 1):

Sudo is aditional package, which has to be installed during Cygwin installation. Have you tried `su` to become superuser?

Anyway, you can always view content of the Cygwin files from Windows...

Comment: I have tried su, but it did not work. I am guessing we have a vanilla Cygwin installation. Also I do not have the install permissions on the server. I will get this installed and try. I was not able to open these files from text editor as well.

Comment: Fortunately I have hit upon a solution from ssh documentation. I have posted it below as an answer. Thanks for your insight!